# WordPress - This theme is broken. The parent theme is missing. Please install the "THEME" parent theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

In my WordPress website, I have created a child theme based on theme Divi, the child theme works perfectly and it has never had a problem, it doesn't display any PHP error message on the screen and the design is fully responsive as I expected.

I normally push the child theme folder and child theme files through GIThub.

Today I have realized that the Appearence->Editor on the admin area in WordPress displays the message:

> **This theme is broken**. The parent theme is missing. Please install the "divi" parent theme.

I can't figure out why that error message come out only now.
Can you please guys advise?

**WordPress Version 4.5.13**

Child Theme CSS header:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Divi Child
 Theme URI:    https://webmarcello.co.uk/
 Description:  Divi Child Theme
 Author:       Marcello Perri
 Author URI:   https://webmarcello.co.uk/
 Template:     divi
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  divichild
*/
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the main Divi theme still installed and not-corrupted? Try re-installing it to make sure. Also, that WordPress version is… uh, less than ideal. It's almost 3 years out of date by now. I doubt that's part of the problem, but it certainly doesn't help.

Comment: `WordPress Version 4.5.13` Time to update WordPress

Comment: I understand that the version of WordPress is old, but is it related to the error message that I get?

Comment: @Xhynk how can I check if the main theme is corrupted?

Comment: You can try switching to the main Divi theme. Or without doing that, you could rename the folder `divi` to like `divi-x` via FTP, and then upload a new copy of the `divi` theme.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this problem, the problem was the attribute `Template: divi` in the header of my child theme CSS file, the word `divi` (which is the parent theme) must have capital `D`.

Here is the CSS header correct:

```css
/*
 Theme Name:   Divi Child
 Theme URI:    https://webmarcello.co.uk/
 Description:  Divi Child Theme
 Author:       Marcello Perri
 Author URI:   https://webmarcello.co.uk/
 Template:     Divi
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  divichild
*/
```

Thanks for the help anyway.

**UPDATE 2023:**

As people suggested below, the Template needs to be set with the exact name of the template folder:

```
Template: <template folder name>
```

Comment: This worked for me except it needed to be lowercase for me. Maybe needs to match folder name for the theme?

Comment: @drwbns Yes you correct, Needs to match parent theme folder name

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using WordPress-Version 4.5.13 - The latest WordPress-Version is 5.5.1!

**You should update WordPress immediatly!**

You can get the latest WordPress-Version [here](https://wordpress.org/download/) or update it right in your admin-dashboard.

After you've updated WordPress, check the parent theme for updates.
Maybe this fixes your problem.

**Note:** Old WordPress-Versions are a high security-risk - bugs and security holes are fixed in newer versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question was regarding the error message, is the version of WordPress related to the error message on the editor page?

Comment: Maybe this bug is fixed in a newer version, if there's a bug and a newer version is available, first update and then check if the error is still there.

Comment: I will update WordPress and I will let you know, but I don't think it's a bug, I believe that the original theme is actually broken for some reason. But I can't understand why